# height/width arguments to geom_jitter interact with log scales

Tags: r, ggplot2

Came across this while exploring some data, and it feels like unexpected behavior, so thought I'd post.

`geom_jitter` takes height/width arguments for how wide the jitter is, with a default value of 40%. This 40% appears to be applied to the original values, when you add log scales. However, if you want to tweak this parameter, the value gets applied after log transformation.

This can be illustrated like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(x=round(rlnorm(2000)), y=round(rlnorm(2000)))


# THESE TWO PLOTS ARE THE SAME
# with jitter
p1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) + geom_jitter(alpha=.1) +
  labs(title='regular scale, jitter with default height/width',
       subtitle = '')
# with jitter, and explicit (but same as default) jitter size
p2 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) + geom_jitter(alpha=.1, height=.4, width=.4) +
  labs(title='regular scale, jitter with 40% height/width',
       subtitle = '<== same as that')


# THESE TWO PLOTS ARE NOT THE SAME
# with jitter and log/log scale
p3 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) + geom_jitter(alpha=.1) +
  scale_x_log10() + scale_y_log10() +
  labs(title='log scale, jitter with default height/width',
       subtitle = '')

# with jitter and log/log scale, and explicit (but same as default) jitter size
p4 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) + geom_jitter(alpha=.1, height=.4, width=.4) +
  scale_x_log10() + scale_y_log10()  +
  labs(title='log scale, jitter with 40% height/width',
       subtitle = '<== NOT the same as that')

(p1 + p2) / (p3 + p4)
```

[image]

Is that expected behavior?

What if I wanted to tweak the jitter width of the underlying value, not of the log-transformed values?

Comment: Seems "expected" to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a nice catch! I guess this is a documentation problem - it's not clear enough. Jitter is **not 40%**, it's **40% of the resolution of the data**.

In `ggplot2:::PositionJitter$setup_params` you can see that there's `ggplot2:::resolution` function applied and it's result is multiplied by `0.4`:

```
list(width = self$width %||% (resolution(data$x, zero = FALSE) * 
    0.4), height = self$height %||% (resolution(data$y, zero = FALSE) * 
    0.4), seed = self$seed)
```

So what you need to do is to apply `ggplot2:::resolution` before passing value to `width`/`height`:

```
geom_jitter(
  width = ggplot2:::resolution(log10(dat$x), FALSE) * 0.4,
  height = ggplot2:::resolution(log10(dat$y), FALSE) * 0.4,
)
```

[image]

All code:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_jitter(
    width = ggplot2:::resolution(log10(dat$x), FALSE) * 0.4,
    height = ggplot2:::resolution(log10(dat$y), FALSE) * 0.4,
  ) +
  scale_x_log10() +
  scale_y_log10() +
  labs(title = 'Scale when resolution is applied')
```